# Should this integral be zero?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

Let $f(z)=\pi e^{\pi\bar z}$ be a function on complex numbers. If $\gamma$ is the square with vertices $0,1,1+i \ \text{and} \ i$ in the counterclockwise sense. I would like to compute:

> $$\int_{\gamma} f(z)dz$$

My guess is using Cauchy theorems the value of this integrations is zero. The problem is when I tried to calculate this integral by brute force I didn't get zero as a value to this integral.

Comment: Why not calculate the integral directly?

Comment: Is the function analytic? I can't remember offhand, but I think it's not analytic on or/and in the contour, which is required for Cauchy-Goursat theorem to hold. I apologise if my memory has failed me.

Comment: What "Cauchy Theorems" ? There must be something like 4792394743 Cauchy Theorems all along the different courses in undergraduate mathematics. Now, the function is *not* analytic.

Comment: Can you not just do this? http://bit.ly/2eIVRzr

Comment: @MichaelBurr It's a long and boring calculation.

Comment: It requires four integral computations, not that tedious.

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is not holomorphic and not even meromorphic because $z \mapsto \bar z$ is not differentiable anywhere:

$$\frac{\bar z - \bar 0}{z - 0} = \frac{(x-iy)^2}{x^2 + y^2} = \begin{cases} -i, \text{ on the path $y=x$} \\ i, \text{ on the path $y = -x$} \end{cases}$$

the same can be done for any other point.

So you can't apply Cauchy's theorem or the Residue theorem. You have to calculate it directly.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an answer but rather a comment.

Comment: @DonAntonio I also have to compute it? It's straightforward

Answer (score 0):

By "Cauchy theorems" I'm assuming you're mainly referring to this:

> If $f(z)$ is analytic on and inside a simple closed contour $C$ and $f'(z)$ is continuous on and inside $C$ then $\displaystyle \int f(z) \, dz = 0.$

But this (and pretty much any related theorem) doesn't apply here because $f(z)$ is not analytic.  A necessary condition for analyticity is $df/d\overline z =0$, but this is clearly not satisfied by the given $f$.

Direct calculation is the way to go here.